Twin circles in a quadrilateral

The circumcenters of the four triangles of a complete quadrilateral along with the two points of completion form two congruent circles (in black).
Surely this must've been done before - what's the formal title for these circles?
Update: These two circles are congruent to the Steiner circle (circle $GHIJ$).

A question.  Do you have a proof or are you looking for one? I do have a proof but can't answer you question since I  am not aware of any earlier occurrence in the literature

Thank you I have a proof - I just wanted to know if this had been pointed out previously before sending in a paper on an already known result.

The fact there are 6 congruent circls. These circles congruent to two Johnson circles and two Steiner circles. So there are 10 congruent circles in this conffiguration. Dao Thanh Oai- VietNam

@ĐàoThanhOai do you have a reference for these 10 circles?  I found 8 circles in my answer below, and expect that these would be "well known" but I could not find a reference.

Not an answer, but too much for a comment.  This is just to point out that there are more of these circles congruent to the Steiner Circle.

What you did for the "opposite" vertices $E,F$ can also be done with the opposite pairs $A,C$ and $B,D$.  In the figure, the red circle is what you called the Steiner Circle, and the black pairs of solid, long-dashed, and short-dashed circles come from the three pairs of opposite vertices.
Just messing around I noticed that these circles are concurrent (in threes) at four points which also happen to lie on a circle that is -- surprise! -- congruent with the rest of the circles.  And each point of concurrency also lies on a side of the quadrilateral.
As for your actual question .. I've browsed through papers like Clawson's Complete Quadrilateral but nothing jumps out. When doing a literature search, bear in mind that the Steiner circle has other names, such as 'circumcentric' (see Clawson) and 'Miguel'
